# How to cast a variant as (or convert to) AnsiChar?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

I'm using Delphi XE2. Pretty self explanatory question. I have a variant in which I'm storing a single character (eg. '?') and I want to cast it as an AnsiChar. If I can't cast it, then how do I convert it. I've tried to cast it the usual way casting is done, but it didn't work. I've tried searching on Google and found no straight forward answers. I'm not interested in the theory of unicode conversion. I'm looking for the reference information in one or two lines of delphi code.

Comment: How is it stored in the Variant. It should be stored as an integral type.

Comment: That's just wishful thinking. In fact you do not have a character stored in this variant. You have stored a string in the variant. Which is of course why your attempts to cast fail. If you want to store a single character, do so rather than using a string.

Comment: I presume that's sarcasm, but I'm not sure what point you are making

Comment: @Sam - if you really want an `AnsiChar` specifically, then your thinking is already beyond 'intuitive', 'abstracted' etc. and concerned with implementation details instead. What's the context out of interest, i.e. why do you need an AnsiChar specifically?

Comment: You also have the possibility to declare your own variant types, should the need arise, [`TCustomVariantType`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE5/en/System.Variants.TCustomVariantType).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is one way to do it:

```
v : Variant;
a : AnsiChar;
...
v := AnsiChar('a'); // Will be stored as an AnsiString
// Check variant
if VarIsStr(v) and (Length(AnsiString(v)) = 1) then
  a := AnsiString(v)[1];  // Cast variant holding an AnsiString to an AnsiChar
//Another way
if (VarType(v) = varString) and (Length(AnsiString(v)) = 1) then
  a := AnsiString(v)[1];  // Cast variant holding an AnsiString to an AnsiChar
```

The variant can hold different string types (AnsiString=varString,UnicodeString=varUString and WideString=varOleStr).

If you are storing your AnsiChar as a byte in your variant:

```
v := Byte(AnsiChar('A')); // Will be stored as a byte
if (VarType(v) = varByte) then
  a := AnsiChar(Byte(v));
```

Note: Storing an AnsiChar as a byte vs. an AnsiString is to prefer, since you avoid heap allocations.

---

Noted in comments that you assign your variants as:

```
v := 'c';
```

This means that your variant string will be in a `varUString` format.

```
if (Vartype(v) = varUString) and (Length(String(v)) = 1) then 
  a := AnsiChar(String(v)[1]);
```

Should you want to cover all bases and have a one-for-all variant conversion routine:

```
function GiveMeThatAnsiCharFromVariant( const v: Variant; var a: AnsiChar): Boolean;
// Accepts UnicodeString,AnsiString,WideString,byte for conversion to AnsiChar;
begin
  Result := False;
  if VarIsStr(v) then
  begin
    case VarType(v) of
    varString :
      if (Length(AnsiString(v)) = 1) then
      begin
        a := AnsiChar(AnsiString(v)[1]);
        Result := True;
      end;
    varUString :
      if (Length(String(v)) = 1) then
      begin
        a := AnsiChar(String(v)[1]);
        Result := True;
      end;
    varOleStr :
      if (Length(Widestring(v)) = 1) then
      begin
        a := AnsiChar(Widestring(v)[1]);
        Result := True;
      end;
    end;
  end
  else
  begin
    if (VarType(v) = varByte) then
    begin
      a := AnsiChar(Byte(v));
      Result := True;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: +1 for identifying the correct way to store a character in a variant

Answer (score 5):

If you variant is holding a AnsiChar (Which is stored as an AnsiString) you can access the `VString` field of the `TVarData` and then cast the value to AnsiString. like so

```
var
 v : Variant;
 a : AnsiChar;
begin
 v:=AnsiString('a'); //this is a variant holding a single AnsiChar 
 if (TVarData(v).VType=varString) and (TVarData(v).VString<>nil) then
   a:=AnsiString(TVarData(v).VString)[1];// or a:= AnsiString(v)[1];
```

If you variant is holding a Char (Which is stored as an String) you can access the `VUString` field of the `TVarData` and then cast the value to AnsiString. like so

```
 v:=String('a');
 if (TVarData(v).VType=varUString) and (TVarData(v).VUString<>nil) then
   a:= AnsiString(VarToStr(v))[1];
```